# How to set proper S3 bucket name for Holdmusic Twimlet

Tags: twilio, twimlet

I'm trying to setup a Twilio number to receive calls and play MP3 files that are on my public S3 bucket. I want to use a HoldMusic Twimlet for that and set this as the WebHook for my number.

Unfortunately I struggle with the proper format of the S3 bucket name. I can get the examples to work (eg com.twilio.music.ambient) [that are given here](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/holdmusic).

However, if I switch to my bucket name in the Twimlet Generator the system yields this error:

> Failed to fetch the hold music.

Let's say my bucket name is `my-bucket`. The ARN is `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket` and the full URL is `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket`

What is the format I have to use?

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have figured it out. The simple bucket name works for the Twimlet: `my-bucket`.

The problem was that I hadn't set the permissions in the bucket correctly. Both the bucket **and** the file(s) have to be set to public.

Comment: Any chance you have a bucket policy json example that worked?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on Amazon and instead just added an XML on my own server that delivered:

[image: xml structure]